# Class that inherits `int` gets odd ghost like variable assignments

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance

For lack of a better title, this is what I got so far.

```
class cordinate(int):
    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = args[0]
        self.y = args[1]

        ## Try to get pixel [0,0] and see what it got:
        if self.x == 0 and self.y == 0:
            print('New Here')
            print(self.x, self.y, self.angle, self.distance_from_edge)

        self.angle = 225
        self.distance_from_edge = 13

        args = [self.distance_from_edge,]
        return super(cordinate, self).__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)

cordinates = [cordinate(0,0), cordinate(2,10), cordinate(3,8)]
```

As expected, this code throws an error:

```
New Here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    cordinates = [cordinate(0,0), cordinate(2,10), cordinate(3,8)]
  File "test.py", line 9, in __new__
    print(self.x, self.y, self.angle, self.distance_from_edge)
AttributeError: type object 'cordinate' has no attribute 'angle'
```

For whatever reason, I tried the following:

```
if self.x == 2 and self.y == 10:
```

This code will output:

```
New Here
2 10 225 13
```

Now, I am sure there's a simple explanation to this and there's no need for panic or start to believe in ghosts..

But I've played around with it but can't make sense of it. What's the explanation of this behavior - does it have a name? How come a newly created instance can have a value that is about to be set 2 rows under?

**Expected value:** Always crashing - Because I purposely placed a print with a not-defined key at the top.
**Python:** 3.5.1 (Windows 8)

Comment: The first argument to `__new__` is **the class** (conventionally `cls`), not the instance (conventionally `self`). Therefore those attributes are already set as long as the *first* call doesn't crash.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're janking my chain? haha. If it's that simple I'll have to re-evaluate how I assign `x` and `y` to this class upon creation.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you're using `__new__` rather than `__init__`?

Comment: @Holloway presumably because they're subclassing `int`, which is immutable.

Comment: @Holloway as JonrSharpe said, it's because I'm subclassing `int`, the real reason for why I'm using it tho is because this is how i was tought these specific inheritance cases works. Wasn't aware of how they actually worked : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from [the data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), the first argument to `__new__` is the class (conventionally `cls`), not the instance (conventionally `self`). Therefore you are setting class attributes on the `cordinate` class (note that that's a typo, and class names should be `CamelCased`) not each instance. As long as the *first* call to `__new__` succeeds, those attributes are set on the class for all subsequent calls.

If you want to set instance attributes in `__new__`, do it *once you have the instance*, e.g.:

```
class Coordinate(int):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(Coordinate, cls).__new__(cls, *args[2:], **kwargs)
      # ^ or 'inst' or whatever you like
        self.x, self.y = args[:2]
        ...
        return self
```

Comment: You are absoluteley correct and thank you for explaining in layman terms and also for including a direct pointer to the documentation. Easy yet fully qualified answer! Cheers!